# compare multiple column with Numpy and panda

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hello my goal and to find which circuit (Nom_ci)
I can't find the right path, I'm trying to find the right method,
I had done it with a set of IF ELIF ... but the times were enormous

Can you help me find the best method

thanks in advance

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re



cycling = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Comp_ci': [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1], 
        'Nom_ci': ['RONCQ_A2_OPTI_SRV_S3', 
                 'RONCQ_A3_SRV_S3, RONCQ_A2_OPTI_SRV_S3', 
                 'RONCQ_A2_TEMP_SRV_S3, RONCQ_A3_SRV_S3, RONCQ_A2_OPTI_SRV_S3', 
                 'RONCQ_A2_SRV_PC_S3, RONCQ_A2_TEMP_SRV_S3, RONCQ_A3_SRV_S3', 
                 'RONCQ_A2_PC_SRV_S3, RONCQ_A2_SRV_S3, RONCQ_A2_TEMP_SRV_S3', 
                 'RONCQ_A2_OPTI_SRV_S3, RONCQ_A2_PC_SRV_S3, RONCQ_A2_SRV_S3', 
                 'RONCQ_A3_SRV_S3, RONCQ_A2_OPTI_SRV_S3, RONCQ_A2_PC_SRV_S3', 
                 'RONCQ_A2_TEMP_SRV_S3, RONCQ_A3_SRV_S3', 
                 'RONCQ_A2_SRV_S3',
                 'RONCQ_A2_PC_SRV_S3'],
        'result hope':['autre','RONCQ_A3_VSR_S3','RONCQ_A3_VSR_S3','RONCQ_A3_VSR_S3','RONCQ_A2_VSR_S3','RONCQ_A2_VSR_S3','RONCQ_A3_VSR_S3','RONCQ_A3_VSR_S3','RONCQ_A2_VSR_S3','autre']
    }
)
print(cycling)

condition=((cycling['Count RSF Circuit']==1) & 
           (cycling['Nom ConcatSet'][0].str.contains("_OPTI").eq(False)) & 
           (cycling['Nom ConcatSet'][0].str.contains("_TEMP").eq(False))&
           (cycling['Nom ConcatSet'][0].str.contains("_PC").eq(False)))


cycling['col3'] = np.where(condition, cycling['Nom ConcatSet'], 'autre')
print(cycling)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT :
Ok, I think I have understood what you tried to achieve : is that it ?

```
temp = cycling.Nom_ci.str.split(', +') # will split on ',' or ' ' (using regex)
print(temp)
print('-'*50)

temp = temp.explode() #will explode the lists to one serie (do note that the indexes are kept untouched)
print(temp)
print('-'*50)

temp = temp.to_frame() #will convert your serie to a dataframe
print(type(temp))
print('-'*50)

temp['match'] = temp['Nom_ci'].str.contains('(_TEMP)|(_PC)|(_OPTI)')==False #will get you a boolean serie (using regex) from your patterns, which will allow you to select the desired strings
print(temp)
print('-'*50)

temp =  temp[temp.match==True] #do select the rows corresponding to your criteria (note that the indexes are still untouched)
print(temp)
print('-'*50)

temp.rename({'Nom_ci':'col3'}, axis=1, inplace=True) #rename your column to whatever you want
print(temp)
print('-'*50)

temp.drop('match', inplace=True, axis=1) #drop the "match" column which is now useless
print(temp)
print('-'*50)

cycling = cycling.join(temp) #join the dataframes based on indexes
print(temp)
print('-'*50)

cycling['col3'].fillna('autre', inplace=True) #fill the "nan" values with "autres"
print(cycling)
```

Comment: Hello
first of all thank you for your help
when we have only one item of information in the cell, this does not pose a problem, it happens to find the main circuit, on the other hand when there are 2, or even three, I cannot find a solution, without do not pass 3 intermediate columns
the goal is to look for an element in the "Nom_ci" column by removing the other 2 (because they have OPTI, TEMP, PC criteria)

Comment: I just changed my answer. Still not sure I have understood your problem here ; if I'm right, you should really be more explicit in your questions (especially explaining that the attended result was in the "result_hope" column, that would have helped a lot !).

Comment: Thank you for your response
on the other hand I retrieve information from a huge array and deisré that COL3 is associated with DF, I tried DF ['CP'] = temp ('col3'), but it does not work, and I do not understand why.

Comment: If you want to join dataframes, you should use either [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) or [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join). Other than that I can't help you more without copy of your code and of your exception traceback...